# Bugs won't print to Pycharm console. Only in log file. How to make it print to Console?

Tags: python, pycharm

I wrote a script whose bugs needed to be logged. So of course I used the logging module. However I have had to make lot of changes to the code and now the errors only print to a log file.

I went ahead and commented out all my logging module uses and it still won't print to console. its so bad that even when I debug in Pycharm, my console doesn't print anything. How can I make Pycharm print to console again?

The logging module is greyed out in the import section so nothing should be using it

Comment: Please share the code sample.

Comment: If I shared my code, people would complain it's too much code. Because you'd need to see the whole code to see what's wrong.

Anyways, I fixed this by removing my if main function. Not sure why it fixed it but it did @PavelKarateev

Comment: This may help https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/setting-log-options.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by removing my if **main** function. Not sure why this worked but it did